# Connecting an array of numpys

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numpys of the same length each. for example:

```
my_list = [np.array([2, 3, 5, 5]),
           np.array([5, 4, 1, 4]),
           np.array([8, 4, 5, 1]),
           np.array([7, 4, 5, 1])]
```

I want to turn the list into 2d numpy:

```
[[2, 3, 5, 5],
 [5, 4, 1, 4],
 [8, 4, 5, 1],
 [7, 4, 5, 1]]
```

The following code does perform the operation but in a sloppy manner.

The result is also not arranged in the desired order:

```
combined = []
for i in my_list :
    if len(combined) == 0:
        combined = i
    else:
        combined  = np.vstack((i,combined))
    
print(combined)
```

What needs to be changed to get the desired result?

Comment: `np.vstack(my_list)`?

Comment: Always assume your question has been asked before and do your research

Comment: Look at the `vstack` docs.  Its argument can be a whole list, not just a list of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way

```
np.vstack(my_list)
```

or

```
np.concatenate(my_list).reshape(len(my_list),-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply doing `np.array(my_list)` can get the job done.